# Postgres: Why DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY expression(s)?

Tags: postgresql

Why I can't retrieve the first distinct row with just any other expression in the order by, why should the leftmost expression be the same expression I used in DISTINCT ON?

Comment: I did see this question already, but it did not answer the "why" in the answer. Even the first answer did not help the person asking the question, nor it explained the concept

Comment: It just says the documentation says we need to do this. But "why" is that required, is nowhere mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the ORDER BY is needed to keep those rows together that share the same value for the "distinct columns". The database processes them sequentially discarding all subsequent rows from the same set. If the rows weren't sorted, this wouldn't be easily possible.

Assume this set of rows:

```
c1 | c2 
---+----
 1 | 100
 2 |  10
 1 | 200
 2 |  15
```

If you want the c1 to be unique and pick the highest c2 you would need to use

```
select distinct on (c1) *
from the_table
order by c1, c2 desc;
```

The `order by` itself will generate the following result:

```
c1 | c2 
---+----
 1 | 200
 1 | 100
 2 |  15
 2 |  10
```

By processing that result row-by-row the database can now efficiently discard every but the first row for each `c1` value by simply checking if that value changes from row to another. If the result wasn't sorted this check would be become far more complicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, makes complete sense to me now.

Comment: This is not clear: you say first "impossible" then "far more complicated". And PG documentation itself only says "result unpredictable". Not clear at all for me.

Comment: @pifor: true, corrected. "Not possible" is probably too far fetched. I think without an explicit order by, the database would need a second pass on the result while doing some hashing to find the correct row that should be kept.